# data in tableview is pile up when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

how to create data in tableViewCell when scrolling not pile up ?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *theCell = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:theCell];

    if (! cell) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:theCell];
    }

    UILabel *data1 = [self createLabelText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayUtama objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"nomer"]]WithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 50) WithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16] WithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell insertSubview:data1 atIndex:0];

    UILabel *data2 = [self createLabelText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayUtama objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"subjek"]]WithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 10, 150, 50) WithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16] WithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell insertSubview:data2 atIndex:1];

    UILabel *data3 = [self createLabelText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayUtama objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"shadowScore"]]WithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 150, 50) WithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16] WithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell insertSubview:data3 atIndex:2];

    UILabel *data4 = [self createLabelText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayUtama objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"finalScore"]]WithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 10, 150, 50) WithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16] WithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell insertSubview:data4 atIndex:3];

    UILabel *data5 = [self createLabelText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayUtama objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"kkm"]]WithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 10, 150, 50) WithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16] WithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell insertSubview:data5 atIndex:4];

    UILabel *data6 = [self createLabelText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayUtama objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Status"]]WithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 10, 150, 50) WithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16] WithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell insertSubview:data6 atIndex:5];

    UILabel *data7 = [self createLabelText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayUtama objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"teachernote"]]WithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 10, 150, 50) WithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16] WithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell insertSubview:data7 atIndex:6];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some images of what is currently produced and what you want to have happen?

Comment: How to ask a question so that people actually know what your problem is and *can* help you?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is everytime the cell is loaded, you are adding a new `UILabel`. This becomes a problem when cells are recycled since they already have labels created and you're creating more.

You should be subclassing `UITableViewCell`, creating the `UILabel`s and layout you want on load, then simply setting information in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. This allows you to recycle cells and improve performance while maintaining layouts and avoiding this "stacking issue" you've found.

**Second Option**

As second, less desirable, option is to move your `UILabel` create methods into the `if (!cell)` block and retrieving them with tags and setting them outside that block. This is less portable and more fragile, however the same efficient effect of reusing labels would be in place. It would look something like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *theCell = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:theCell];

    if (! cell) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:theCell];

        UILabel *data1 = [self createLabelText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayUtama objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"nomer"]]WithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 50) WithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16] WithColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        data1.tag = 1;
        [cell insertSubview:data1 atIndex:0];

        // ... Load Other labels and give unique tags

    }

    UILabel *data1 = [cell viewWithTag:1];
    data1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayUtama objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"nomer"]]];

    // ... Load other labels by tag and set text.

    return cell;
}
```